# ffmpeg wait before recording desktop

Tags: 12.04, ffmpeg

Is it possible to make ffmpeg wait a couple seconds before starting to record? if so how is there another way to start an ffmpeg script besides from the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

If you're starting `ffmpeg` from the terminal, you could use `sleep` to wait a few seconds before starting it.

```
sleep 10 && ffmpeg
```

…will start `ffmpeg` after 10 seconds.